# Can we add a shortcut to go to the review queues?

Tags: feature-request, moderation

I'm allergic/too lazy to use the mouse, can we add a keyboard shortcut to jump to the review queues ?

[image]

Comment: @NormalHuman ah, turns out it's already [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245009/add-go-to-review-as-a-keyboard-shortcut)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ctrl-F, "REV", ? Depends on browser, but it's certainly accessible without using the mouse!